# How does one install the necessary libraries to use MultipartEntity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been following at least a half dozen different StackOverflow questions on how to install the necessary libraries to be able to use MultipartEntity in Android Studio.

What libraries specifically are needed?
What steps are needed to setup the libraries in Android Studio and what do the import statements look like?

Here is the MultipartEntity doc: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultipartEntity is a class that's part of a number of http packages related to android.

Its A class in native android package that has been left to languish by Android's owner. The namespace of the native package collides with - causes Classpath issues - some of the more robust replacement packages.

Its A class in [apache httpclient lib](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html)

IMO - Its really more a question of the libs you want to include in AS projects using Gradle and maybe Maven repos for project building blocks for your network connections/services/HTTP.

So, if you want to use the Maven lib for apache httpclient ( including your class MME ) in AS project , review the following:

[MME sample](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java)

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5

https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/

To use the apache in your project  this in your 'build.gradle'

```
 compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
```

Be sure to include 'maven central' repo in your top level 'build.gradle'...

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

This in your code where specific class names overlap (use 'HC4' suffix)
   apache and native android Namespace collisions need to be avoid!

```
import ....MimeMultipartEntityHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDeleteHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGetHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPostHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPutHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntityHC4;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntityHC4;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntityHC4;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtilsHC4;
```

**NOTE**  apache sample programs do NOT account for android namespace collisions. You will have to figure that out. If MME is NOT part of native android http package then the HC4 suffix as shown above would NOT BE REQUIRE.